# Office 2013 window edges cause white/black bars in other applications

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

Office 2013
Windows 7 Pro 64 bit
Dell 6530 w/ Intel + nVidia 4000 graphics

Office applications will regularly cause bleed through with the few pixels around their window and show white/black bars on other windows above them.  I think there's supposed to be some kind of fade effect outside the windows, and that's the root cause.  It seems that only the verticals do this.

This effect happens over time, and in Word, Excel, and Outlook.  Probably PowerPoint too, but I don't use it that often.

An example: I have an Outlook find window behind Firefox.  At some point, there will be a white or black bar that lines up with the side of the find window that removes useful information from Firefox.

Here's a screenshot of the bars bleeding through Firefox. [image: In this case they are black]

I thought this was a Z buffer issue in the video card drivers, or a problem with certain monitors, but I've updated drivers, and I see it on all the monitors (I think).

Any ideas what I can look at to troubleshoot this?  Have you seen or heard of this problem?  I can't seem to find anything about it online.

Comment: If you suspect it is related to Office, have you installed all updates for Windows and Office?

Comment: You may find this article helpful - [Performance and display issues in Office client applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2768648)